# Does QiQi have a specialty dish?

Tags: genshin-impact

Most characters in Genshin seem to have a specialty dish -- produced when using a normal base recipe, the character has a chance to produce their special version of the dish.  For example, if you use Amber to cook Steak, you have a chance to produce the dish "Outrider Champion's Steak".

I've seen a [list here](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/how-to-make-all-special-dishes-in-genshin-impact) showing most of the characters' custom dishes. But it doesn't list Qiqi's custom dish. That gets me wondering -- does she have a custom dish, or does it not exist at all? It would be at odds with the game saying that every character has a custom dish.

Comment: I'm not sure since i don't have her (;-;) but i'd bet on that bird egg soup you can buy the recipe of at her pharmacy. Or maybe some recipe that has cocogoat's milk lmao

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qiqi's speciality dish is the dish "*No Tomorrow*", based off the original dish "*Come and Get It*".

[image]

The base recipe is available in Liyue Harbor after you have reached Adventure Rank 40.

[image]

The dish requires:

- Raw Meat x3
- Fish x3
- Rice x3
- Tofu x1